# How to set default value in asynchronous ng-options

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous, ng-options

The ng-options get asynchronous . How can I set the default value?

```
<select class="form-control" 
        ng-options="item.id as item.value for item in mInsu.INS_MAX_AMOUNT track by item.id"
        ng-model="custInfo.mInsu.selAmount" required>
</select>
```

I tried to do like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="custInfo.mInsu.selAmount" required>
    <option ng-repeat="item in mInsu.INS_MAX_AMOUNT" value="{{item.id}}">{{item.value}}</option>
</select>
```

Luckly, it can meet my requirement.

So, why can't set default value in asynchronous ng-options?

Comment: try init model with default value

Comment: It can work when I delete 'track by ...'. Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LsbhL1xh/2/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the below lines in your controller:

```
$scome.custInfo.mInsu.selAmount = mInsu.INS_MAX_AMOUNT[0].id;
```

which assigns the first value as default.

Comment: Create a fiddle and share the url here so that i can take a look what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: It can work when I delete 'track by ...'. Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LsbhL1xh/2/)

Comment: Working fiddle [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csrujanreddy/ezhdnng4/1/)